JavaFX transparent window events
I am trying to create a custom JavaFX window, with rounded corners and a drop shadow:

Right now there are no system buttons, menu or anything. The primary stage has StageStyle.TRANSPARENT and the primary scene is also filled with Color.TRANSPARENT.
The structure of the window is as follows (from Scene Builder):

The StackPane and the GridPane are styled as follows:
#support-pane { /* StackPane */
    -fx-padding: 12px;
    -fx-background-color: transparent
}

#main-pane { /* GridPane */
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-background-radius: 7px;
    -fx-effect: dropshadow(three-pass-box, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), 10, 0, 3, 3);
}

For illustrative purposes, this is how the window would look like if the StackPane was cyan:

The sole purpose of the StackPane is to be a transparent canvas on which the inner GridPane can cast its shadow. Obviously, the problem is that the cyan edge acts as if it's part of the window, so, for example, any clicks on that area will bring the whole window into focus.
Is it possible to make the transparent (cyan) edge completely ignore any events and just let clicks through? Or is it possible to implement a true window with round corners and a drop shadow, without such workarounds?

If you're referring to OS-level mouse events (such as those that bring the window into focus), I don't think that can be done via JavaFX; you would somehow need to manage it at the native OS level. Calling setMouseTransparent(true) will prevent mouse events being propagated to the JavaFX event handling system, but it doesn't sound like that's what you are looking for.

I've thought of trying setMouseTransparent but I can't apply it to the scene anyways, only to the panes.

Duplicate (unanswered) question How to focus on applications behind the JavaFX window when clicking on transparent areas?

I believe this is at least partly OS-dependent. On Windows 10/11, any fully transparent part of a window acts as if the mouse is hovering over whatever is behind the window. Note, however, that the drop shadow is not considered to be transparent. Meaning its not the "cyan" pane that's the problem, but the drop shadow effect on the red pane. Again, this is the behavior I see on Windows 10/11; I don't have access to other operating systems for testing.

I've tried this with other windows such as IntelliJ's IDEA, and although the dropshadow is pretry wide, clicking on it seems to let the clicks through.

I'm not sure how the IntelliJ (new UI) window is set up, but it's done perfectly: they have a custom title bar, snap works, drop shadow, minimize/maximize/close animations, etc.
